# How to test methods that rely on private parameters in constructor in Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I do not have the permission to edit the component file at all, so that's not an option. I have to test a method that relies on a private variable to run successfully.

```
  candidateSmartMatch(): void {
    const jobAddressFormGroup = this.locationModel.formGroup.get('JobAddress');
    if (!!jobAddressFormGroup) {
      this.subs.sink = jobAddressFormGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        filter((value: PostLocationInterface) => !!value.CityState || !!value.Zip)
      ).subscribe(
        (value: PostLocationInterface) => {
          const formattedAddress = this.formatAddress({
            StreetAddress1: value.StreetAddress1,
            StreetAddress2: value.StreetAddress2,
            CityState: value.CityState,
            Zip: value.Zip,
            DispCity: ''
          });
          this.candidateSmartMatchManagementService.setJobLocation(formattedAddress);
          this.jobCompetitionService.setLocation(formattedAddress);
        });
    }
  }
```

The variable `this.locationModel` comes from the constructor, where it is input as a private parameter. There is an `initialize()` method that sets the public variable `form` like so:

```
this.form = this.locationModel.formGroup;
```

If I could get the value of `this.form` in the unit test, that might solve my issue, but calling `component.initialize()` doesn't seem to make a difference. I have also tried creating a mock form in my test. Here is my test:

```
  it('call setJobLocation method', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(candidateSmartMatchManagementService, 'setJobLocation');
    component.initialize();
    component.form = new FormGroup({
      StreetAddress1: new FormControl('Street1'),
      StreetAddress2: new FormControl('Street2'),
      CityState: new FormControl('Miami, FL'),
      Zip: new FormControl('33015'),
      FormattedAddress: new FormControl('Street1 Street2 Miami, FL 33015')
    });
    component.candidateSmartMatch();
    expect(candidateSmartMatchManagementService.setJobLocation).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Basically, I am just trying to test a scenario in which the method `candidateSmartMatch` successfully calls the method `setJobLocation`. I am using a mock service for `candidateSmartMatchManagementService`, but it contains a mock method for `setJobLocation`.

EDIT:

I changed my test method to use the locationModel mock as suggested but it's still saying "Expected spy setJobLocation to have been called"

```
  it('call setJobLocation method', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(candidateSmartMatchManagementService, 'setJobLocation');
    jobLocationModel.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      StreetAddress1: new FormControl('Street1'),
      StreetAddress2: new FormControl('Street2'),
      CityState: new FormControl('Miami, FL'),
      Zip: new FormControl('33015'),
      FormattedAddress: new FormControl('Street1 Street2 Miami, FL 33015')
    });
    component.candidateSmartMatch();
    expect(candidateSmartMatchManagementService.setJobLocation).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Here is my model mock:

```
export class JobLocationModelMock {
  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    JobAddressID: new FormControl('test'),
    JobRelocation: new FormControl(),
    FormattedAddress: new FormControl(),
    JobAddress : new FormGroup({
      JobRelocation: new FormControl(),
      CityState: new FormControl(),
      Zip: new FormControl(),
      StreetAddress1: new FormControl('test'),
      StreetAddress2: new FormControl(),
      DispCity: new FormControl()
    }),
    JobAddresses: new FormArray([])
  });
  private model: PostJobService = new PostJobService();
  init(): Observable<any> { return Observable.of([]); }

  defineModel() {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to show the mocked model code? Its hard to diagnose what is really happening without it.

Comment: OK, I have updated it with the model mock code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are sending the locationModel through the constructor of the current component.  If that is the case, then you can pass a mocked model during the set up of the TestBed.  Without seeing your setup code, I am going to take a shot at an example.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LocationModel, useValue: MockLocationModel
        }
      ],
      declarations: [Component]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

As far as making the test work it looks as though you have a listener that is checking for value changes in the form.  At some point you just need to set/update some value in the form after calling `component.candidateSmartMatch();` in the test.

Comment: That sounds like it should work. I will give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it looks like that model has already been mocked. I edited my test method to be as shown in my edited post. I am assuming I need to do something to change the value of locationModel within the method I am testing.